# jquery Checking Image Height width server issue

Tags: jquery, html

I have this jquery to checks the image height and width.  It works in jfiddle.net

http://jsfiddle.net/XJNp3/5/

But it doesn't not work on the server or on my local machine.  I have tried in IE and chrome.  Like I said both work in jsfiddle but not in production.  Thanks

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        var _URL = window.URL;
        $("#myFile").change(function () {
            var file, img;
            if ((file = this.files[0])) {
                img = new Image();
                img.onload = function () {
                    if (this.width != 57) {
                        alert('Please ensure the Image width is 57');
                        document.getElementById('myFile').value = "";
                    } else if (this.height != 59) {
                        alert('Please ensure the Image height is 59');
                        document.getElementById('myFile').value = "";
                    }
                    else {
                        //alert('perfect');
                    }
                };
                img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);
            }
        });
</script>
   <input type="file" id="myFile" />
```

Comment: We no nothing at all about your other environments. I'm not sure what you're hoping for here.

Comment: Where exactly does the code fail? Are there any errors in the console? Does the script alert something when you try to upload an image?

Comment: I'm sorry.  In my local environment, it just doesnt do anything.  No errors nothing in the console.  iis 7.5  aka my local.

Comment: Have you tried copying the latest version of jQuery and putting it into an external js file and linking to it through that instead of google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's because JSFiddle automatically wraps your code in a `$(document).ready()` ( or maybe `$(window).load()` ).

In your actual code, you need to do this yourself. ie

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //All your jQuery code here
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using.   
//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){